# How to add active class on top menu and active class and icon on sidebar menu?

Tags: jquery, css

So i have this website and i want when user click on top menu to add only active class but when he choose something from sidebar menu to add icon arrow next to it.Any suggestion how can i do that?

http://muzej.midori.lapps.ws/visiting-us/

this is how i add class on every link

```
$(function() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  $('nav a').each(function(e,i) {
    if (href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: And what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When active class is added to your `a` tag, write little bit of css.

Add this code and you will get something like this in the  sidebar area  [**OUTPUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tv1i.png)

```
.left-content li.menu-item a.active:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f105';
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

This piece of code will add a angle-right to the a tag.

Comment: @None You are welcome mate :)